# Fatal error: Call to undefined method simple_html_dom::first_child()

Tags: fatal-error, simple-html-dom

sometimes when i use simple html dom methods like save(), children(), first_child() i get an error that says Call to undefined method. why i get this error?

Comment: are you sure that, by "file_get_html" command, html file is taken successfully?

Comment: yes, html is taken successfully i found that this error comes up whenever using that method is not applicable in that section of code but i don't know why php give undefined method Fatal Error maybe something wrong in php ini

Comment: anyway i use curl to get html as a string and then ->load the string

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this late answer is usable for you. I have got the same error message and find out that for simple_html_dom, the usage is following:

$h = new simple_html_dom;
$h -> load($your_html_string);  // for example  blah blah blah...
instead of using (very important):
$h -> fist_child();
you need to:

$f ->$h -> find($tag, 0); //here $tag is 'div'
$f -> first_child;

unfortunately if you do not know your tag, you need to use preg_match to get it. hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not node or null
So, you must check it.

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 0):

Simple html dom exposes two classes. simple_html_dom_node and simple_html_dom. If you try to use a node method on a dom or vice versa, it will cause this error.